# Importing the FANN Library into Dev C++

Tags: c++, installation, fann

I downloaded the FANN library from http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/download/

Im using windows 8, and it does not give any directions on how to install it.

I have these contained inside the download:

[image]

What do I do so I can successfully run the sample programs provided? Thank you

Comment: Did you read the README?  What did that tell you?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to 'install' as such, as FANN is distributed as a dll/lib file. In this directory, you will find:

- The compiled files will be in the `bin` folder. This includes the compiled FANN dll/lib files and any compiled examples.
- The source code for FANN will be in the `src` folder.
- The source code for the provided examples will be in the `examples` folder.
- Any Visual Studio projects will be in the `VS2010` folder - only useful if you are using Visual Studio.
- The cmake files to help build the FANN dll/lib files are in the `cmake` folder.

I would recommend looking at the examples. To use FANN you need to incorporate the appropriate FANN dll/lib file into your project.